# Dates range containing with infinite intervals using ifs

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, plsql, overlap

I have a function in `Oracle` that checks if the first date contains the second one. There is no problem with it, because `[a, b]` contains `[x, y]` if `x => a and y <= b and x <= y`. Works fine for defined `start/end date 1` and `start/end date 2`. But now I want to modify it. If any of given `'starting'` or `'ending'` dates are `NULL` it should be treated as `+-infinite`.

It's a code:

```
  FUNCTION CONTAINS(p_START_DATE_1 DATE, p_END_DATE_1 DATE,
   p_START_DATE_2 DATE, p_END_DATE_2 DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

   lv_RESULT VARCHAR2(1);
  BEGIN 
       lv_RESULT := 'N';      

       IF (/* milions of conditions here */) THEN
         lv_RESULT := 'Y';
       END IF;

       RETURN lv_RESULT;
  END CONTAINS;
```

**For instance:** Suppose that `p_START_DATE_1` is `NULL`. In this case that code:

```
SELECT MY_PACKAGE_SQL.CONTAINS(
       NULL,
       TO_DATE('01/12/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
       TO_DATE('01/02/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
       TO_DATE('01/05/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
FROM DUAL;
```

... should return `Y`, because first date range is `(-infinite, 01/12/2014]` and it contains  `[01/02/2012, 01/05/2012]`.

Now my problem... I know I can use additional `"IFs"` to check `NULLs`. And I have to do it using `"IFs"` (a boss ordered me to do it:S). Do you have any idea how to do it in a "smart" way using only `"IFs"`?

Comment: How are you going to represent negative infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to this, using available routines for handling NULLs, would be something like:

```
FUNCTION CONTAINS(a DATE, b DATE,  -- does interval [a, b] contain [x, y]?
                  x DATE, y DATE)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  lv_RESULT           VARCHAR2(1);
  dtPositiveInfinity  DATE := TO_DATE('31-DEC-9999 23:59:59',
                                      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
  dtNegativeInfinity  DATE := TO_DATE('01-JAN-4712 BC 00:00:00',
                                      'DD-MON-YYYY BC HH24:MI:SS');
BEGIN 
  lv_RESULT := 'N';      

  IF NVL(x, dtPositiveInfinity) >= NVL(a, dtNegativeInfinity) AND
     NVL(y, dtNegativeInfinity) <= NVL(b, dtPositiveInfinity) AND
     NVL(x, dtNegativeInfinity) <= NVL(y, dtPositiveInfinity)
  THEN
    lv_RESULT := 'Y';
  END IF;

  RETURN lv_RESULT;
END CONTAINS;
```

However, you say you can't use COALESCE and thus I'll infer you can't use NVL either, in which case perhaps the following would work:

```
FUNCTION CONTAINS(a DATE, b DATE,  -- does interval [a, b] contain [x, y]?
                  x DATE, y DATE)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  lv_RESULT           VARCHAR2(1);
  dtPositiveInfinity  DATE := TO_DATE('31-DEC-9999 23:59:59',
                                      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
  dtNegativeInfinity  DATE := TO_DATE('01-JAN-4712 BC 00:00:00',
                                      'DD-MON-YYYY BC HH24:MI:SS');
  aOrNegativeInfinity  DATE := a;
  bOrPositiveInfinity  DATE := b;
  xOrPositiveInfinity  DATE := x;
  yOrPositiveInfinity  DATE := y;
  xOrNegativeInfinity  DATE := x;
  yOrNegativeInfinity  DATE := y;
BEGIN 
  lv_RESULT := 'N';      

  IF a IS NULL THEN
    aOrNegativeInfinity := dtNegativeInfinity;
  END IF;

  IF b IS NULL THEN
    bOrPositiveInfinity := dtPositiveInfinity;
  END IF;

  IF x IS NULL THEN
    xOrPositiveInfinity := dtPositiveInfinity;
    xOrNegativeInfinity := dtNegativeInfinity;
  END IF;

  IF y IS NULL THEN
    yOrPositiveInfinity := dtPositiveInfinity;
    yOrNegativeInfinity := dtNegativeInfinity;
  END IF;

  IF xOrPositiveInfinity >= aOrNegativeInfinity   AND
     yOrNegativeInfinity <= bOrPositiveInfinity   AND
     xOrNegativeInfinity <= yOrPositiveInfinity
  THEN
    lv_RESULT := 'Y';
  END IF;

  RETURN lv_RESULT;
END CONTAINS;
```

And if the use of multiple IF statements is problematic, perhaps the following would be acceptable:

```
FUNCTION CONTAINS(a DATE, b DATE,  -- does interval [a, b] contain [x, y]?
                  x DATE, y DATE)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  lv_RESULT           VARCHAR2(1);
  dtPositiveInfinity  DATE := TO_DATE('31-DEC-9999 23:59:59',
                                      'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
  dtNegativeInfinity  DATE := TO_DATE('01-JAN-4712 BC 00:00:00',
                                      'DD-MON-YYYY BC HH24:MI:SS');
BEGIN 
  lv_RESULT := 'N';      

  IF CASE x WHEN NULL THEN dtPositiveInfinity ELSE x END >=
           CASE a WHEN NULL THEN dtNegativeInfinity ELSE a END AND
     CASE y WHEN NULL THEN dtNegativeInfinity ELSE y END <=
           CASE b WHEN NULL THEN dtPositiveInfinity ELSE b END AND
     CASE x WHEN NULL THEN dtNegativeInfinity ELSE x END <=
           CASE y WHEN NULL THEN dtPositiveInfinity ELSE y END
  THEN
    lv_RESULT := 'Y';
  END IF;

  RETURN lv_RESULT;
END CONTAINS;
```

Not tested on animals - you'll be first!

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic, expressed as a `case` statement:

```
select (case when (p_START_DATE_1 is null or
                   p_START_DATE_1 >= p_START_DATE_2 or
                   p_START_DATE_1 is null and p_START_DATE_2 is null
                  ) and
                  (p_END_DATE_1 <= p_END_DATE_2) and
                  (p_START_DATE_1 <= p_END_DATE_1 or p_START_DATE_1 is null
              then 'Y'
              else 'N'
         end)
```

You can also express this perhaps more easily using `coalesce()`:

```
select (case when coalesce(p.START_DATE_1, to_date('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) > p_START_DATE_2 and
                  (p_END_DATE_1 <= p_END_DATE_2) and
                  coalesce(p.START_DATE_1, to_date('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) <= p_END_DATE_2
             then 'Y'
             else 'N'
        end)
```

This method will be easier if you want additional logic for other columns to be `NULL` (and you have extreme dates that you can use for the `NULL` values).

Comment: If I'm not wrong it works only for my example. If I set e.g. `p_END_DATE_2 := NULL`, it won't work. How to generalize that case for all the parameters (All of them could be `NULLs`)?

Comment: @Nickon . . . Your question is specifically about starting dates, so generalizing to all four dates is a different question.  However, you can probably solve the problem just by using `coalesce()` in your logic with appropriate extreme values.

Comment: @Nickon . . . Then use `case` statements or set the `NULL` values to an extreme before doing the comparison.

Comment: And can you use NVL? How about NVL2? Or LNNVL?